# formal way of saying "get a feel"

Tags: formal-language

> I plan to publish by doing MS with thesis to get a feel of research.

How can I convey this without sounding informal. Is this already formal for a statement of purpose for a graduate school?

Comment: First of all, don't use abbreviations like *MS*. Also it is not clear what you are trying to say, so more explanation is needed. Seems like "I plan to publish (something) by doing (something) to get a feel *for* research."

Comment: First, find out what term the university uses for "MS with thesis" and use that. In My case it was "Masters of Engineering by Research", with differentiated it as a Masters based on physical time spent in the lab, with a thesis on my topic at the end. I presume your university will use similar terminology.

Comment: The university uses the term "MS with thesis".

Comment: What does MS stand for?

Comment: Masters of Science would be my guess. You may also see it abbreviated as MSc, MSci, depending on location.

Answer (score 1):

- to develop a basic understanding of
- to improve my knowledge of
- to gain experience in

Given what you have stated in the comments, I would probably formalise the sentence as a whole

- I plan to publish by **completing a** MS with thesis to **improve my knowledge of** research.
- I plan to publish by **completing a** MS with thesis to **develop my understanding of** research.

There's still a level of ambiguity on *what* you plan to publish though.

Comment: publish a research paper